# How to run in a phone Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio

I upgraded Android Studio to 3.5 version and now when I use Run or debugg it run directly the emulator and never give me the option to select my phone. Where do I need to change this config?

Comment: enable USB debugging in your phone. the emulator is not equal to your phone

Comment: USB debugging is already enabled, the problmen is that in the latest version of Android Studio when I chose to debug, that opened a dialog box and there I could select my device or emulator (even if I didn't have my device connected), but now when I choose debug it starts the emulator directly, even if my device is connected to my PC and it has enabled debugging

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Run" at the top > Edit configurations > Look for deployment target options > Choose "Open select deployment target"

Comment: Apparently in this version the dialog box doesn't exist but in previous versions it works well, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.5 doesn't ask you to select devices and emulators. Instead, they moved to select menu on toolbar.

[image: example]

Comment: I tried there but I never saw my device and after to research I realized that my problem was that my anti-virus blocked the abd and android studio didn't detect my device.
Thank you.